# First row with specific value operation in python

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I am trying to solve a problem in python as stated below:

I have Name as a category. So for every category, say , A & B here, I want to have 1's as long as my "Diff" column(X-Y) in positive. Now for the first negative row in each group(highlighted in the table), I want to divide "Diff" of the previous row and "Value" of current row.

```
Date    Name    Value   X   Y   DIFF    Output
01/10/20    A   3   100 20  80  1
02/10/20    A   4   100 40  60  1
03/10/20    A   5   100 60  40  1
04/10/20    A   6   100 120 -20 6.66666667
05/10/20    A   7   100 140 -40 0
06/10/20    A   8   100 200 -100    0
07/10/20    A   9   100 400 -300    0
08/10/20    A   10  100 500 -400    0
09/10/20    A   11  100 600 -500    0
01/10/20    B   3   200 20  180 1
02/10/20    B   4   200 40  160 1
03/10/20    B   5   200 60  140 1
04/10/20    B   6   200 120 80  1
05/10/20    B   7   200 140 60  1
06/10/20    B   8   200 200 0   0.3
07/10/20    B   9   200 400 -200    0
08/10/20    B   10  200 500 -300    0
09/10/20    B   11  200 600 -400    0
```

So, output(6.666666)=40/6
The rows in each group("Name") is sorted by date.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is this a pandas dataframe? Add the `pandas` tag if it is.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add the data in text form (so we can copy it) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
df['Output'] = ((df['DIFF'].shift() / df['Value']) * (df['DIFF'] > 0).diff() * ~(df['DIFF'] > 0)).fillna(0) + (df['DIFF'] > 0)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
        Date Name  Value    X    Y  DIFF    Output
0   01/10/20    A      3  100   20    80  1.000000
1   02/10/20    A      4  100   40    60  1.000000
2   03/10/20    A      5  100   60    40  1.000000
3   04/10/20    A      6  100  120   -20  6.666667
4   05/10/20    A      7  100  140   -40  0.000000
5   06/10/20    A      8  100  200  -100  0.000000
6   07/10/20    A      9  100  400  -300  0.000000
7   08/10/20    A     10  100  500  -400  0.000000
8   09/10/20    A     11  100  600  -500  0.000000
9   01/10/20    B      3  200   20   180  1.000000
10  02/10/20    B      4  200   40   160  1.000000
11  03/10/20    B      5  200   60   140  1.000000
12  04/10/20    B      6  200  120    80  1.000000
13  05/10/20    B      7  200  140    60  1.000000
14  06/10/20    B      8  200  200     0  7.500000
15  07/10/20    B      9  200  400  -200  0.000000
16  08/10/20    B     10  200  500  -300  0.000000
17  09/10/20    B     11  200  600  -400  0.000000
```

---

Note: I'm not sure about the output value in row 14. In your code is `0.3`, but according your description it should be `60/8`, thus `7.5`